# Need Help to Create a Folder based off a filename via Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have

```
\\192.168.1.2\Video\PodCasts\MyPodcast S01E01.mp4
\\192.168.1.2\Video\PodCasts\MyPodcast S01E02.mp4
\\192.168.1.2\Video\PodCasts\MyPodcast S01E02.mp4
\\192.168.1.2\Video\PodCasts\MyPodcast S02E01.mp4
\\192.168.1.2\Video\PodCasts\MyPodcast S02E02.mp4
\\192.168.1.2\Video\PodCasts\MyPodcast S02E03.mp4
\\192.168.1.2\Video\PodCasts\MyPodcast S03E01.mp4
\\192.168.1.2\Video\PodCasts\MyPodcast S03E02.mp4
\\192.168.1.2\Video\PodCasts\MyPodcast S03E03.mp4
```

I want to create

```
\\192.168.1.2\Video\PodCasts\Podcasts S01
\\192.168.1.2\Video\PodCasts\Podcasts S02
\\192.168.1.2\Video\PodCasts\Podcasts S03
```

And I have a PS Script to create the folders and move the files within it..

I have so far

```
$Show = Read-Host "Show"

cd "\\192.168.1.90\video\$Show"

Get-ChildItem -Filter "$Show S*.*" -File | ForEach-Object {
$series = $_.Name -replace '.*(S\d{2}).*', '$1'

# create the target path inside the same directory and create if needed
$destination = Join-Path -Path $_.DirectoryName -ChildPath $series
if (!(Test-Path -Path $destination -PathType Container)) {
    $null = New-Item -Path $destination -ItemType Directory
}
# move the file to the new path
$_ | Move-Item -Destination $destination -Force
}
```

This works

\192.168.1.2\Video\PodCasts\S01\MyPodcast S01E01.mp4

I would like to adjust to do

\192.168.1.2\Video\PodCasts\MyPodcast S01\MyPodcast S01E01.mp4

I dont see where in $destination to adjust it

Comment: Your `$destinationFolder` is the same as the source folder. Also `$FileName = $_.BaseName -match ' s01'` makes `$FileName` either $true or $false. Use `$_.FullName` as path for the Move-Item cmdlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code can be simplyfied by getting the list of files in the shared directory `\\192.168.1.2\PodCasts` and looping through them in a ForEach-Object loop.

Then, get the series number `S01`, `S02` etc. from the file's name, create a folder in the shared directory `\\192.168.1.2\PodCasts` with that series name and move the file there:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path '\\192.168.1.2\PodCasts' -Filter 'MyPodcast S*.mp4' -File | ForEach-Object {
    $series = $_.Name -replace '.*(S\d{2}).*', '$1'
    # or do something like this: $series = ($_.BaseName -split ' ',2)[1].Substring(0,3)

    # create the target path inside the same PodCasts directory and create if needed
    $destination = Join-Path -Path $_.DirectoryName -ChildPath $series
    if (!(Test-Path -Path $destination -PathType Container)) {
        $null = New-Item -Path $destination -ItemType Directory
    }
    # move the file to the new path
    $_ | Move-Item -Destination $destination -Force
}
```

Before:

```
\\192.168.1.2\PODCASTS
    MyPodcast S01E01.mp4
    MyPodcast S01E02.mp4
    MyPodcast S02E01.mp4
    MyPodcast S02E02.mp4
    MyPodcast S02E03.mp4
    MyPodcast S03E01.mp4
    MyPodcast S03E02.mp4
    MyPodcast S03E03.mp4
```

After:

```
\\192.168.1.2\PODCASTS
+---S01
|       MyPodcast S01E01.mp4
|       MyPodcast S01E02.mp4
|
+---S02
|       MyPodcast S02E01.mp4
|       MyPodcast S02E02.mp4
|       MyPodcast S02E03.mp4
|
\---S03
        MyPodcast S03E01.mp4
        MyPodcast S03E02.mp4
        MyPodcast S03E03.mp4
```

<sup>P.S. In your example filelist, file 'MyPodcast S01E02.mp4' is doubled</sup>

Comment: That Worked Perfect, Thank you....  How can it be modded to create MyPodcastS01, MyPodcastS02, MyPodcastS03, etc... instead of S01

Comment: @DavidBowyer That's easy. Just change the destination to:

`$destination = Join-Path -Path $_.DirectoryName -ChildPath  ('MyPodcast{0}' -f $series)`

Comment: Thank you Theo... I am new to this...  mod the Script with $destination = Join-Path -Path $_.DirectoryName -ChildPath  ("$Show {0}" -f $series) and it worked perfect, thank you again...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, never run destructive (New, create, rename, move, delete, update, clear...) code without a validation step.

Is this what you are after?

```
Clear-Host
@(
    'D:\PodCasts\MyPodcast S01E01.mp4',
    'D:\PodCasts\MyPodcast S01E02.mp4',
    'D:\PodCasts\MyPodcast S01E02.mp4',
    'D:\PodCasts\MyPodcast S02E01.mp4',
    'D:\PodCasts\MyPodcast S02E02.mp4',
    'D:\PodCasts\MyPodcast S02E03.mp4',
    'D:\PodCasts\MyPodcast S03E01.mp4',
    'D:\PodCasts\MyPodcast S03E02.mp4',
    'D:\PodCasts\MyPodcast S03E03.mp4'
) | 
ForEach {
    $SourceFolder      = [regex]::matches($PSItem, '.*\\PodCasts').Value
    $DestinationFolder = [regex]::matches($PSItem, 'S0\d').Value

    If (Test-Path -Path "$SourceFolder\$DestinationFolder")
    {
        Write-Verbose -Message  "Processing $SourceFolder\$DestinationFolder" -verbose
        Move-Item -Path $PSItem -Destination $destinationFolder -WhatIf
    }
    Else
    {
        Write-Warning -Message "
            Attempt to move a file to nonexistent folder, failed. 
            Creating the resource: $SourceFolder\$DestinationFolder
            "
        New-Item $DestinationFolder -ItemType Directory -WhatIf
        Move-Item -Path $PSItem -Destination $destinationFolder -WhatIf
    }
}

# Results
<#
WARNING: 
            Attempt to move a file to nonexistent folder, failed. 
            Creating the resource: D:\PodCasts\S01
            
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: D:\Scripts\S01".
What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: D:\PodCasts\MyPodcast S01E01.mp4 Destination: D:\Scripts\S01".
...
#>
```

If the folder already exists

```
# Results
<#
VERBOSE: Processing D:\PodCasts\S01
What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: D:\PodCasts\MyPodcast S01E01.mp4 Destination: D:\Scripts\S01".
VERBOSE: Processing D:\PodCasts\S01
What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: D:\PodCasts\MyPodcast S01E02.mp4 Destination: D:\Scripts\S01".
...
WARNING: 
            Attempt to move a file to nonexistent folder, failed. 
            Creating the resource: D:\PodCasts\S02
            
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: D:\Scripts\S02".
What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: D:\PodCasts\MyPodcast S02E01.mp4 Destination: D:\Scripts\S02".
#>
```

Comment: I have a lot more than just those 9 vids so i slightly mod the script but it does not work

Comment: WARNING: 
            Attempt to move a file to nonexistent folder, failed. 
            Creating the resource: \S08

Comment: Clear-Host
cd 'Z:\Podcast\'


@(
 'Z:\Podcast\'
) | 
Get-ChildItem | ForEach {
    $SourceFolder      = [regex]::matches($PSItem, 'Z:\Podcast\').Value
    $DestinationFolder = [regex]::matches($PSItem, 'S0\d').Value

    If (Test-Path -Path "$SourceFolder\$DestinationFolder")
    {

Comment: Write-Verbose -Message  "Processing $SourceFolder\$DestinationFolder" -verbose
        Move-Item -Path $PSItem -Destination $destinationFolder -WhatIf
    }
    Else
    {

Comment: Write-Warning -Message "
            Attempt to move a file to nonexistent folder, failed. 
            Creating the resource: $SourceFolder\$DestinationFolder
            "
        New-Item $DestinationFolder -ItemType Directory -WhatIf
        Move-Item -Path $PSItem -Destination $destinationFolder -WhatIf
    }
}

Comment: error looks like
WARNING: 
            Attempt to move a file to nonexistent folder, failed. 
            Creating the resource: \S08
            
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: Z:\Podcast\S08".
What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: Z:\Podcast\MyPodcast S08E08.mp4 Destination: Z:\Podcast\S08".

Comment: i tried to run PS ISE as Admin, nothing  and i tried to do the IP, nothing

Comment: WARNING: 
            Attempt to move a file to nonexistent folder, failed. 
            Creating the resource: \S08
            
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: \\192.168.1.90\video\Podcast\S08".
What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: \\192.168.1.90\video\Podcast\MyPodcast S08E08.mp4 Destination: \\192.168.1.90\video\Podcast\S08".

PS Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\192.168.1.90\video\Podcast>

Comment: Exception calling "Matches" with "2" argument(s): "parsing "Z:\Podcast\" - Malformed \p{X} character escape."

Comment: I of course did this on my local machine, and this works as expected. AS shown by the result set displayed. So, this was not tested on a remote server. Yet, as a rule, what I gave you notwithstanding, you have to often escape backslashes when doing this on remote targets. So a double backslash [\\] is really [\\\\] and of course single backslash [\], is really [\\].  This is not just a PowerShell specific thing. You can check yourself by doing one file at a time.